# Invoice total in row n, payment in row n+k, using dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a table of payments to calculate interest. The column where the payment is applied takes its values from the column where the invoice totals are listed, however, the payment is applied k days after the period ends.

[image: table in question]

I had partial success doing it using this formula:

```
IFERROR(INDEX($F$12:$F$25,MATCH(D12,$G$12:$G$25,1)),0)
```

Where column G is a helper column with the dates of payment, basically period end + k, but since it only accounts for the period end, in monthly and semimonthly periods, sometimes the nearest lower date of payment was on the same period, so I MUST also account for the period start for this to not happen. I've been helped using an array formula like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,SMALL(IF(F$12:F12>0,ROW(F$12:F12)),COUNT(1/((C$12:C12-C$12>C$7)+(D$12:D12-C$12>C$7))))),0)
```

And it works well and it does not require a helper column. But since it's an array formula, and this table is not for my usage, that's not suitable.

I would like to know if I can do this without an array formula and built-in excel 2013 functions.

**Edit:**
This formula does it:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($D$12:$D$25+$C$7>=C12)*($D$12:$D$25+$C$7<=D12)*($F$12:$F$25))`

But if there are blanks in column D that result from a formula, it returns an error. So the following formula is more stable:

`=SUMIFS($F$12:$F$25,$D$12:$D$25,">="&C12-$C$7,$D$12:$D$25,"<="&D12-$C$7)`

This one effectively places the payment rows within the range of dates it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can replace `SMALL` with `AGGREGATE` like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F:F;AGGREGATE(15;6;(ROW(F$12:F12)/(F$12:F12>0));COUNT(1/((C$12:C12-C$12>C$7)+(D$12:D12-C$12>C$7)))));0)
```

`AGGREGATE(15;6;;)` is the same as `SMALL`, but it ignores errors. This lets you switch out the `IF(F$12:F12>0,ROW(F$12:F12))` for the quotient `(ROW(F$12:F12)/(F$12:F12>0))`. Every row-number divided by a `FALSE` produces an error which gets ignored by `AGGREGATE`.

For the `COUNT`-part I cannot say, what it is doing, as my results don't look like yours (i copied your formula).
I guess it works as an offset.

Can you test my formula and tell me if it is working without cse? Else we need to find a replacement for the `COUNT`-part. I currently cant test it as I am on Office 365 and don't know if i can activate the old CSE-functionality.

[image]

Comment: The count part was calculating the `k` argument from the `SMALL` function. From the inside to the outside, `C$12:C12` is to evaluate from the current row to the top, e.g. in the fifth row of the table, it looks like this `C$12:C17`. `C$12:C12-C$12` returns days elapsed. `C$12:C12-C$12>C$7` returns days elapsed higher than the pay term, it will return 0 until it finds one, but as soon as it finds one, it will find the next, and so forth, that's why the `SMALL` function was used, because it ranks them only when higher. The inverse count is used to ignore the lowers with `DIV/0!`.

Comment: But it's also hard to maintain for me, it took me far too much time to barely grasp its mechanism, as I still don't quite understand why it sums the following number. I couldn't understand it, so I discarded it. Then, someone helped me find another two solutions that I could understand. One with SUMPRODUCT and another with SUMIF. I will post those later as soon as I can to update this thread. By the way, your formula returned 0 in all rows for my dataset. Still, thank you very much. I'll post the solution in the upcoming hours. Should I upvote?

Comment: But `C$12:C12-C$12>C$7` with fixed line in `C$12` produces always true, as in your picture `C12` is empty. Was also thinking about `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: Is it working as expected, if you delete an amount in the middle of the invoice total column?

Comment: For the dataset that you kindly created to do your tests, this formula would place the payment amount where it should, according to columns C and D: `=SUMIFS($E$12:$E$25,$D$12:$D$25,">="&C12-$C$7,$D$12:$D$25,"<="&D12-$C$7)`
Sorry for the delayed response, it's been a crazy week.